# How to properly wrap a JSON database result within an object

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js, ember.js, laravel-4

I created an API for my various SPA's using a Laravel resource controller that works like a charm. While BackboneJS has no problem with the default JSON response, EmberJS expects the result wrapped in a singular and plural named JSON object depending on if it's fetching a single model or a collection of models.

**What I already know**

- Convert the JSON result to an array wrap it and convert it back to JSON.
- Wrapping every result in an object.
- Change the result comming from the database call to an array with `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

**Question**
How to properly (using the cheapest process) create the wrapped JSON responses, so without converting the results back and forth between JSON, Arrays or Objects?

A snippit from the Laravel resource controller:

```
<?php

class ResourceController extends Controller {

     ...

     /**
        * Display a listing of the resource.
        *
        * @return Response
        */
     public function index() {
            return Model::all();
     }


     /**
        * Display the specified resource.
        *
        * @param  int  $id
        * @return Response
        */
     public function show($id) {
            return Model::find($id);
     }

     ...

}
```

Comment: You can use wrapped format on server side, and make extra job for backbone.js. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558679/how-to-properly-wrap-a-json-database-result-within-an-object/23558993#23558993) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will wrap the original `Eloquent` database result for a Laravel application with a database configured as `"fetch" => PDO::FETCH_CLASS`. It creates a new object of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and wraps the `Eloquent` result in a `models` property. This way it's formatted properly for using it with **Ember data** without any conversions.

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index() {
   $index = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
   $index['models'] = Model::all();
   return $index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with following structure. Always, return your json response in wrapped format like(I assumed you have User model);

```
{
    "user": [
        {"name": "Hüseyin"},
        {"surname": "BABAL"},
        {"title": "Software Developer"}
    ]
}
```

This is suitable for `ember.js`. For `backbone.js`, you need to do some extra simple job like following;

```
var User = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User, 
    url: '/api/userInfo',
    parse: function(response) {
            return response.user;
        });
    }
});
```

By doing this, you will only one format rest service, and you just need to do some extra job for only `backbone.js`

**Update:**

Think about `index` action, you can do that like;

```
public function index() {
    return Response::json(array("user" => Model::all()));
}
```

Result will be wraped with `"user"`, you can use response as json on frontend. The result will be;

```
{
    "user": [
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey Huseyin, that is actually what I provide in the question. I need to know how to wrap the result in an elegant way by using Laravel (PHP). What you wrote I already have, as I wrote it works like a charm for BackboneJS.

Comment: @sidneydobber Could you please state your code in your question about returning json part on controller ? I can help you well

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this is already doing a `JSON` to `array` back to `JSON` conversion. As I state in the question, this is exactly what I'm trying solve.

Comment: @sidneydobber sorry I have added `toArray()` mistakenly. In laravel4, if you return model, laravel detects it json, or array. You can use both. Default, it is an array. I have put that array in wrapped one, and just did an array-to-json conversion.